# ¿Cómo solucionar error UnsupportedClassVersionError?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlets, tomcat

Estoy aprendiendo un poco API Servlet y Java EE, estoy siguiendo un curso donde se crea un formulario, se manda y a través de una clase que extiende de HttpServlet muestro los values, por ejemplo el mail, opciones elegidas, etc.

De ser necesario subo el código en algún lado para mostrar, tengo solo dos archivos un index.jsp y una clase FormServlet, y el pom.

Cuando envío el formulario obtengo el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/ferdev/apiservlet/webapp/form/FormServlet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (no puedo cargar clase [org.ferdev.apiservlet.webapp.form.FormServlet])
```

Entiendo por lo que vengo leyendo que es porque lo compile en java 8 y ahora lo estoy compilando en 16, el problema es que jamás lo compile en 8.
Sumo información que lo estoy haciendo en Intellij Community.

Java versión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi proyecto también usa 16
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Instale java 8, para cambiar la versión de java del proyecto a 8 pero tampoco funciona.

Tengo instalado tomcat, que lo descargue como zip y cuando lo levanto, voy al directorio bin y le doy a startup.bat y cuando lo bajo shutdown.bat.

Estuve leyendo este link
[Fix UnsupportedClassVersionError](https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion)
Pero el problema sigue siendo el mismo.

Mi pregunta en fin, es si alguien sabe como solucionarlo, alguna otra forma.

Y también saber, si quizás, utilizando Eclipse por ejemplo es mas fácil de solucionar este problema.

*SUMO*: también, por las dudas, intente eliminando el war y el directorio que se crea en webapps dentro de tomcat (también en work), volví a compilar pero sigue el error.

Quedo atento a cualquier pedido de mas información del error o mis componentes, o lo que necesiten para así pueda solucionar este error.
Desde ya, muchísimas gracias!

***UPDATE 1:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No, jamás lo había compilado con java 8.
Estuve trabajando todo momento con java 16, si tengo instalado java 11 pero en ningún lado lo utilice.
Y si instale java 8, después de ver este error y querer compilarlo con 8, ya que entiendo que dice que solo responde a 8. Pero antes no lo había instalado ni habia compilado con 8.
Y en el pom, tengo

```
<maven.compiler.source>16</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>16</maven.compiler.target>
```

Comment: Fijate con qué versión de java corre tu servidor  Tomcat y compila con la misma versión  de Java.

Comment: Hola @JuanCarlosGuibovich , me podrías guiar como veo la versión de java de Tomcat? De todas formas busco info para verificar eso, pero por las dudas si sabes, genial.

Comment: Edita el startup.bat y encuentra la linea donde  ejecuta el java. Tambien  puedes ver la versión en la consola.  ¿Cuál es la versión de  Tomcat?

Comment: Por el mensaje de error "this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0", el  tomcat está ejecutando con java  1.8. Dices que  lo compilaste con java  1.8?

Comment: Instalaste  el  java  1.8 JRE y el  JDK?

Comment: Si usas  Maven para  generar to  proyecto  asegurate que el POM.XML tenga  la versión correcta  java 1.8

Comment: Ahi te respondi en la pregunta misma, en UPDATE 1. @JuanCarlosGuibovich.  Voy a intentar algo que lei, que me parece algo innecesario pero bueno es borrar todo, tomcat y el proyecto, y hacer todo de vuelta. Me sigue pareciendo loco pero voy a intentar eso.

Comment: En el pom.xml  tienes  que  cambiarlo  a 8,  si  es que vas a reinstalar el mismo tomcat.  Lo raro  que al parecer  el tomcat levanta  con  la  16 pero  el mensaje  de error hace alusión a la 1.8. Quizá  reinstalando se  corrija.